# numeric keypad for text field on mobile browsers

Tags: html, mobile-safari, mobile-browser

I want to show a numeric keypad to user for a text field like credit card number, reservation number with hyphens(-) etc.

I tried to use the following

```
type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I have tested only on Safari on iphone 5 & 6.

with type and inputmode as "tel", I am able to get numeric keypad with special characters but not sure if its a good hack.

I would like to know if there are any better options than this.

Comment: `input type='tel'` is a standard HTML5 specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#telephone-state-(type=tel) ) and is therefore not a hack. Any browser that supports HTML5 (including mobile phone browsers) should be able to render the control.

Comment: yes it is but I meant to say that its a hack because we are using telephone number type for text fields which need numeric keypad. if its the only way then probably its name should be changed to convey numeric-text or something

Answer (score 0):

To show a numeric keypad, you can use `<input type="number">` along with `pattern` attribute to match your requirements. The regex can also have maximum limit specified to match your credit card or reservation number.

Just note that Android Chrome browser doesn't have key events (keyup, keydown, keypress). So user will be able to enter it & you will be able to validate it later - either on blur event or click of submit button.